# WPF Code binding not work

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have problem with binding in code.

I have Control with X, Y double properties and dependency properties.

```
    public double X
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(XProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(XProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public double Y
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(YProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(double), typeof(VisualPin));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(double), typeof(VisualPin));
```

In other control I have Line and I try to use binding to Line end point like this:

```
var xBinding = new Binding("XProperty") {Source = _startPin};
var yBinding = new Binding("YProperty") {Source = _startPin};
Line.SetBinding(Line.X1Property, xBinding);
Line.SetBinding(Line.Y1Property, yBinding);
```

All data in all properties are OK, I checked that, but binding doesn't work. I don't have idea why... (All controls are on one Canvas)

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry, my fault. Problem was in first parameter in register dependency property - X instead of XProperty! Solved...

Comment: Please post this as an answer and accept it OR consider deleting the question if you are not anticipating anything from community. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, my fault. Problem was in first parameter in register dependency property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("X",    typeof(double), typeof(VisualPin));
public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(double), typeof(VisualPin));
```

Instead of:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("XProperty",    typeof(double), typeof(VisualPin));
public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("YProperty", typeof(double), typeof(VisualPin));
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug this kind of situation you should look at the XAML by using a tool like snoop WPF. This will show what the actual bindings are.

It might be your binding is there, but not updating. To fix this your class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Whenever you want to update the value, like after setting the value, call the following function with the name of the property:

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```